# Dimensional analysis of displacement in $t$th seconds

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis

The expression of [displacement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_law_of_odd_numbers#) in $t^{th}$ seconds can be derived as:

$s_{t^{th}} = s_t - s_{t-1} = ut + \dfrac{at^2}2 - u(t-1) - \dfrac{a^2}2(t-1) = u + \dfrac{a}2(2t - 1)$

Why is it lacking dimensional homogeneity?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the units of your 1. The 1 in $t-1$ is not a dimensionless 1. It is the dimensionful quantity $1 \text{ s}$. Fix that and it works.